# Trouble logging into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Getting error:

Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Restarted the service, server, and all the computers in between.  I suspect it's not connecting to the domain server - any way to check about this?

Comment: How are you logging in?  Via Enterprise Manager / Sql Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124130559/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/05/25/40489.aspx), hopefully its of use to you ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sqlcmd with the -E option, to make sure it's trying to use Integrated Security.